# how to store data in eth blockchain without gas

Tags: ethereum

I want to create an app where I store some data/text in the Ethereum blockchain, I know it's possible with smart-contracts but is there a way to store without paying gas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to pay gas because this is essentially data that every person who is running a node must store on their computer